# Can mapping the results of a linq query being mapped to a class be simplified?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I've got a class called Customer that has several properties, i.e. FirstName, LastName, City, State

The Customer class has some data annotations to fix naming and other things. (This class is being used as a model for MVC)

I've got a Linq query against an EF5 entity that has those same fields. Is there a simple way to map the query results to the class other than:

```
customer.FirstName = item.FirstName;
customer.LastName = item.LastName; 
customer.City = item.City; 
etc.....
```

I have run across references to automapper (and others) but was wondering of there are other options based on the identical nature of the results and class?

Comment: There's really only two options: automation via something like AutoMapper or doing the object to object mapping manually.  Personally I was using AutoMapper in my initial projects, but, I've switched to just doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating the objects at that time, using object initalizers is probably the cleanest coded solution.

```
var model = new myMvcModel()
{
    FirstName = input.FirstName,
    LastName = input.LastName,
    City = input.City
}
```

Otherwise using reflection or AutoMapper as Ek0nomik suggest are your only solutions that I could suggest.

Like Ek0nomik I prefer to do it manually rather than AutoMapper. Even created a VS macro to inspect both objects and output some scaffolding.